# Conversion of RTF To HTML

Tags: rtf, aspose.words

Im trying to convert rtf to html using Aspose.words
following is the code snippet that i have used
 string path = @"C:\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Html_AsposeWords\Html_AsposeWords\ExampleRtf.rtf";

```
        LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
        loadOptions.LoadFormat = LoadFormat.Rtf;
        Document doc = new Document(path,loadOptions);
        //doc.OriginalLoadFormat 
        doc.Save(@"C:\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Html_AsposeWords\Html_AsposeWords\Output.html");
```

but when debugged document's originalfileformat it is "Text" instead of rtf

and  my generated html output is not what i expected html tags with rtf content

Can you please help us on this

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the source code. I tried with a sample RTF file at my end, it produces similar formatted HTML. Could you please share the source RTF? Also try with the latest version of Aspose.Words

Comment: This is the sample RTF.Placed in a file and saved as ExampleRTF.rtf {\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang3079{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red0\\green128\\blue0;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\cf1\\f0\\fs17 Rot.\\cf0\\fs17  \\cf2\\fs17 Gr\\'fcn.\\cf0\\fs17  \\cf3\\fs17 Blau.\\cf0\\fs17  \\i\\fs17 Kursiv.\\i0\\fs17  \\strike\\fs17 Durchgestrichen. \\ul\\strike0 Unterstrichen.\\ulnone\\fs17  \\b\\fs17 Fett.\\b0\\fs17\\par} .Im using Latest version of Aspose.words ,version 14.9.0

Comment: Can you share the file via dropbox or other service? If I copy this to disk and save file as .rtf, MS Word also shows these RTF tags. Ideally, if MS Word can open it correctly, then Aspose.Words should too

Comment: I could now convert success fully from rtf to html ...There was some issue in the document ,thanks for the response...But now im facing an issue ,where i'm trying to save the document to html and HTMLSaveOptions.CSSStyleSheetType=CSSStyleSheet.Embedded ..I can see now my html document has style tag with few styles defined in it ,but html body has few tags with inline styles .can you please help me on this

Comment: Yes, I noted some styles within the tags too. Please post this issue in Aspose forums (http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). The support team will log a bug for it and do the needful.